# Initialising specific elements of a static const array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, g++, gnu

I have some C that I need to convert to C++.

It does something like this:

```
enum
{
   ELEM0,
   ELEM1,
   ELEM2,
   ELEM3,
   ELEM4,
   MAX_ELEMS
} 

#define LEN 16

static const char lut[MAX_ELEMS][LEN] =
{
    [ELEM2] = "Two",
    [ELEM3] = "Three",
    [ELEM1] = "One",
    [ELEM4] = "Four",
    [ELEM0] = "Zero"
}
```

In practice I have hundreds of elements without any order in the array. I need to guarantee that the entry in the array ties up the enumeration to the appropriate text.

Is it possible to initialise an array using positional parameters like this in -std=gnu++11?

Comment: What do you mean you need to convert this to C++? This code will work just as well in C++ as it does in C. Are you asking if there's a better way to achieve the same result in C++? I think you need to provide more context to get an answer to that question.

Comment: I thought that initialisation of an array by designators wasn't valid C++?

Comment: @mattnewport: The syntax is supported in C99 as _C99 designator_, he needs in C++11 too (or something like that).

Comment: Ah, ok, I wasn't familiar with that syntax so I misread the question, thanks.

Comment: clang implements c99 designators as an extension in all modes (except it's not an extension in C99 mode, obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Per gcc [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.1/gcc/Designated-Inits.html#Designated-Inits), *Designated Initializers* do not exists in GNU C++.

> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C89 mode as well. **This extension is not implemented in GNU C++.**

Doesn't this solve you problem (although it's run-time):

```
static const std::map<int, std::string> lut =
{
    std::make_pair(ELEM2, "Two"),
    std::make_pair(ELEM3, "Three"),
    std::make_pair(ELEM1, "One"),
};
```

Comment: That's sort of what I was wondering. I knew that the previous approach wouldn't fly, so a more "C++" approach seemed like the option. It's all down to how well I can graft it into the existing codebase. Thanks!

Comment: An unordered_map might be a better choice than a regular map as it will have runtime performance characteristics closer to the original code.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> lut{MAX_ELEMS};` might be a better structure.  Then you do indexing exactly like before and you can insert in whatever order you want.  With small string optimization it also won't do more than 1 heap allocation during the construction.